# What's the difference between these two Quicksort partition functions?

Tags: python, quicksort

```
def PartitionDemo(a,p,r):
    x=a[p]
    start=p
    end=r
    while start<end :
        while start<end and a[end]>=x :
            end-=1
        while start<end and a[start]<x :
            a[start]=a[end]
            start+=1
            a[end]=a[start]
    a[start]=x
    return start

def Partition2(a,low,high):
    key = a[low]
    while low < high:
        while low < high and a[high] >= key:
            high -= 1
        while low < high and a[high] < key:
            a[low] = a[high]
            low += 1
            a[high] = a[low]
    a[low] = key
    return low
```

`PartitionDemo` I wrote myself, and `Partition2` I copied it from the internet. However, `PartitionDemo` doesn't run normally; it can not jump out the loop. They use the same logic, I think, but `Partition2` works well.

I tried writing Quicksort in C++, Java and Python, but I don't understand what's going wrong in Python.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "doesn't run normally?" Please add your input, desired output, and actual output (make this as short as possible to illustrate the problem).

Comment: the program didn‘t jump out the loop and it does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PartitionDemo has

```
while start<end and a[start]<x :
```

where Partition2 has

```
while low < high and a[high] < key:
```

so it looks like yours should be

```
while start<end and a[end]<x :
```

replacing the second start with end

Comment: why it is different from the C++ logic？from the end finding the bigger and from the start finding the smaller？

Comment: What is the C++ code? I was just pointing out the difference between the two python functions, how they were not using the same logic.